# Why does my cookie value not persist across pages?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a WordPress site where we're tracking users with cookies unique to the session.  I have the following code in my functions.php file:

```
if (!session_id())
    session_start();

// session user id:
if (isset($_COOKIE["my_user_id"])) {
    $my_user_id = $_COOKIE["my_user_id"];
}
else {
    $my_user_id = uniqid();
    setcookie("my_user_id", $my_user_id);
}
```

And on each page:

```
echo $_COOKIE["my_user_id"];
```

I would expect this to show the same user ID on each page when I was clicking around- however, the user ID is changing for different pages, though it remains the same throughout multiple clicks on the same page.  Wouldn't a cookie value be site wide?

Comment: If you're already using sessions, why don't you just use the session ID?

Comment: Post the common difference between the pages (e.g. directories, subdomains, etc). If nothing else, post a page it works on and a few pages it doesn't.

Comment: @icktoofay- it's just an example- the point is why doesn't the value persist.

Comment: @Jason- It 'works' on all pages, just not across pages.  I'm trying to understand what scenarios could possibly lead to this.  I can't post all the code from my pages here, suffice to say the above code is the same across all pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that the Wordpress cookie path isn't being set to the `/` value. See the arguments for [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).